# How to prove the representation theory of permutation groups (S3) also satisfies the group definition?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, representation-theory

Take S3 group for example, if I associate the permutation with the permutation of the three unit vectors. Then I can write:

$${p((1,2)) = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]},{p((1,3)) = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]}$$

Then, the product of p((1,2)) and p((1,3)) should be p((1,3,2)) because (1,2)(1,3) = (1,3,2) but instead I got:

$${p((1,2))p((1,3)) = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]}$$

which is p((1,2,3)). Could someone please tell me where went wrong?

Comment: You're probably working on the "wrong" side.  Does it turn out right if you multiply in the other order?

Comment: But by the definition of representation theory, shouldn't p(1,2)p(1,3) = p(1,3,2) ?

Comment: No, multiply the matrices in the other order.

Comment: I agree with @Randall. I think you should compute $BA$ instead of $AB$.

Comment: Could you please tell me why the order of matrix multiplication is not the same as (1,2) * (1,3)?

Comment: Because you are working column-centric instead of row-centric (or vice versa).

Comment: Do you mean (1,2)*(1,3）is row centric? Is this a definition?

Comment: No, it just matters.  The way you choose to represent permutations (acting on rows or acting on columns) affects the way the matrix representation works.  It might cause things to appear to come out in the "wrong" order, just as if you were the kind of person that thinks $f \circ g$ means $f$ first, $g$ second.  It's not wrong, just different.

Comment: I am wondering that when I choose to represent permutations to act on columns,  how it indicates that the product p(1,2)p(1,3) should be BA where B and A are the representations of p(1,3) and p(1,2)?

Answer (score 1):

You never state your definition of $p(\sigma)$, and the examples you give are insufficient to deduce the one you are using (since they both have $\sigma^{-1}=\sigma$). There is only one proper way to define $p(\sigma)$ so that it becomes a representation of $S_n$, namely such that $p(\sigma)\,e_j=e_{\sigma(j)}$ for all$~j$ (where $e_j$ is the $j$-th standard basis vector), in other words where $p(\sigma)_{i,j}=\delta_{i,\sigma(j)}$: there is an entry $1$ in *row* $\sigma(j)$ of *column* $j$. According to this definition your product matrix is indeed $p((1,3,2))$, as you would like.

Specifically since $(1,3,2)$ sends $1\mapsto3$, one has $p((1,3,2)(e_1)=e_3$ so the first column of $p((1,3,2))$ is $e_3=(0,0,1)^\top$; similarly $(1,3,2)$ sends $2\mapsto1$ and $3\mapsto2$, so the second and third columns are $e_3=(1,0,0)^\top$ respectively $e_3=(0,1,0)^\top$, as in your final matrix. The fact that $p(\sigma)\,e_j=e_{\sigma(j)}$ is the proper rule in general follows from the simple computation
$$
p(\sigma)p(\rho)\,e_j=p(\sigma)\,e_{\rho(j)} =e_{\sigma(\rho(j))} =p(\sigma\circ\rho)\,e_j\qquad\text{for all $j$}.
$$

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't understand this answer. Do you mean the only proper definition is to use row as basis vectors? Why I cannot choose each column as a different basis?

Comment: @L霞客 I don't quite understand your comment ("choose each column as a different basis" makes no sense), but I expanded my answer a bit. I view vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ as column vectors, but permutation matrix _is not a permutation_ of standard basis vectors; rather it is a matrix $P$ such that _left multiplication by $P$_ (the map $v\mapsto P\,v$) permutes the standard basis, that is, it sends $e_j\mapsto e_{\sigma(j)}$ for some permutation $\sigma$. That matrix $P$ should equal $p(\sigma)$.